# Does the order of javascript makes a difference?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering if the order of the javascript in a page will affect how things work? If yes, is there any problem on my way of arranging them?

```
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/sb-admin-2.min.js"></script>

<script src="vendor/chart.js/Chart.min.js"></script>

<script src="vendor/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script src="vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/demo/chart-area-demo.js"></script>

<script src="js/demo/chart-pie-demo.js"></script>

<script src="js/demo/datatables-demo.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: And 2 versions/copies of Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Yes it makes a huge difference and you have made the mistake of including TWO versions of jQuery, bootstrap and datatables. You need to remove

- `<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>`
- `<script src="vendor/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>`
  and
- `<script src="vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>`

and move the bootstrap one to before the data tables

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/sb-admin-2.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/chart.js/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/demo/chart-area-demo.js"></script>
<script src="js/demo/chart-pie-demo.js"></script>
<script src="js/demo/datatables-demo.js"></script>
```

I would personally have EITHER CDN OR downloaded versions

But take a look at the guidelines

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/

https://cdn.datatables.net/

Comment: There are actually 2 references to Bootstrap

Comment: And two for datatables

Comment: did you meant this bootstrap- <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
??

Answer (score 0):

The order of the javascript files in an html file only makes a difference if they are interdependent. For example if you have a script that uses JQuery and you have declared the jquery script after your script, you will have problem. So when you have a script (or scripts) that is used from another script (or scripts) declare first the script (or scripts) that is used and then the script (or scripts) that uses it.